# Just walk across/on this

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to translate something from a show in my native language. In this sentence,  what sounds the best:

> You just have to walk on this.
>
> You just have to walk across this.

A person was asked to walk the carpet (not "the red carpet"), it was something magical and the person who walked it might get really lucky.

Or will it just be:

> Just walk this.

Comment: Either. It depends on the context. What are you trying to express? What do you mean to *this*? A floor tile that triggers a trap would require walking ***on*** (the tile). Moving from one end of a room to the other would require walking ***across*** (the floor). In your scenario, what is the precise situation with the magic carpet?

Answer (score 1):

**On** - used to show that something is in a position above something else and touching it, or that something is moving into such a position [def.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on)

**Across** - from one side to the other of something with clear limits, such as an area of land, a road, or a river [def.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/across)

As @Jason mentioned, both are viable options, it just depends on the context.

*On* doesn't give much detail, it just means he was above and touching the carpet at some point in some place (or multiple). *Across*, however, implies he walked from one place on the carpet to another.

[Here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/across-over-or-through) is a useful little link explaining some other prepositions you could use.